# Cloze deletion doesn't work

Tags: anki

The message "Please edit this note and add some cloze deletions" still showed up when I've used the correct note type(Cloze) and added at least one cloze deletion( {{c::..}} ). Why?

[image: This is the evidence]

Interestingly, when I added a cloze deletion in the card **using Cloze note** type, the warning still showed up "Warning, the cloze deletion will not work until you switch the top to Cloze". [[image: But the note type is Cloze][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGNkY.png)

Anyone could give me some suggestions?

I understand this is not a language-related questions so if you know where is the best place to post this question, please feel free to make a comment. Also, Cloze deletions used to help me a lot on learning English. Thanks Anki!

Comment: For support for Anki, please go to [AnkiWeb](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/help.html) or [Tenderapp](https://anki.tenderapp.com/).

Comment: Sam Tan, would you sign up on Super User SE if I migrated your question there? (If not, migrating the question may result in a "zombie question".)

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens when the code for formatting cloze cards is deleted, missing or damaged.

To fix this problem:

1. Click "Decks"
2. Select a deck and then select "Study Now"
3. In the lower left hand corner select "Edit"
4. In the upper left corner select "Cards"
5. Add the following code to the fields: Front Template, Styling, and Back Template

This code if for Front Template, only add what is between the curly brackets.

{{cloze:Text}}

This code is for Styling, again only add from .card through to lightblue;}

.card {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}

.cloze {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: blue;
}
.nightMode .cloze {
 color: lightblue;
}

This code is for Back Template, again only add from the first to last curly bracket.

{{cloze:Text}}
{{Extra}}

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: this does not work for me. i have tried to find solutions online but in vain, convinced that this is currently unsolvable.